# Fixing legends and color scheme of ggplot2 bubble grid plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

**Problem**

I'm trying to create a bubble grid heatmap such as the one found [here](https://albert-rapp.de/posts/ggplot2-tips/14_scaled_heatmaps/14_scaled_heatmaps.html).
I am facing several problems, however, in adapting this code. My code so far is:

```
ggplot(yzlong2, aes(x = Period, y = Statement)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = Avg, fill = Avg, size = Count), shape = 21) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = 'top',
    text = element_text(color = 'grey40', size = 20)
  ) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 15, guide='none') +
  scale_fill_gradient(high = "blue", low= "red", name="Average",
                    labels = c("5", "4", "3", "2", "1"),
                    breaks = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1))
```

There are several issues I am facing with this code:

1. How can I remove the old blue gradient legend for fill while keeping the new fill legend?
2. How can I change the color scheme of the new fill legend by selecting an intermediate color? I'd like the color scheme to go from red to white to blue. If there is a way to add more colours that might be even better because the Avgs are quite tightly distributed
3. How can I change the scale of the fill legend go from 1 (red) to 5 (blue)?

[image: Plot as it currently stands]

**Data**

```
structure(list(Statement = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", 
"A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A16", 
"A17", "A18", "A19", "A20", "A21", "A22", "A23", "A24", "A25", 
"A26", "A27", "A28", "A29", "A30", "A31", "A32", "A33", "A34"
), Period = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Mar-1930", "Apr-1930"
), class = "factor"), Avg = c(4.6, 4.2, 4.6, 4.2, 4.2, 4.8, 4.2, 
3.6, 4, 4.2, 4.6, 4.6, 4.2, 4.2, 4.8, 4.6, 4.6, 4.33333333333333, 
4.5, 4.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 
4.33333333333333, 3.5, 3.83333333333333, 4, 4.5, 4.33333333333333, 
4.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 
4.66666666666667), Count = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -34L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Environment**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How can I remove the old blue gradient legend for fill while keeping the new fill legend?

It looks like you don't actually use your color argument, and you could just remove `col = Avg` from your `aes()` function. In **ggplot2**, when it comes to shapes with an inside like circles `color` is for the outline, and `fill` is for the insides.

So removing `col = Avg` is one option. If you want to keep it for some reason but just don't want the legend, add `+guides(color = 'none')` to your code to get rid of the color legend.

2. How can I change the color scheme of the new fill legend by selecting an intermediate color? I'd like the color scheme to go from red to white to blue. If there is a way to add more colours that might be even better because the Avgs are quite tightly distributed
3. How can I change the scale of the fill legend go from 1 (red) to 5 (blue)?

The `scale_fill_gradient2()` scale function incorporates a "middle". You can also make it run the entire range from 1 to 5 using the `limits` option. Note that this will give you a fairly narrow color range, since most of your data is only over a narrow range of that scale. The only way to really fix that is to pick low and high colors that are even farther apart. No real way around that - if you want 1 and 5 to have their own colors, then the small range of your data will naturally only cover a tiny part of that range. At best you could start messing with weird transformation functions to make your tiny data range cover a wider share of the color spectrum you've specified.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(yzlong2, aes(x = Period, y = Statement)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Avg, size = Count), shape = 21) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = 'top',
    text = element_text(color = 'grey40', size = 20)
  ) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 15, guide='none') +
  scale_fill_gradient2(high = "blue", mid = 'white', low= "red", name="Average",
                      midpoint = 3,
                      limits = c(1, 5))
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there actually a way to add 5 points to the color scale?  I'm finding that the while to blue transition is not distinct enough still to show changes from one date to another

Comment: You mean like five distinct ordered colors instead of a continuous gradient? try using scale_fill_steps2 instead of scale_fill_gradient2 https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_steps.html